# const char * and char *

Tags: c++, char, constants

I understand that

```
char *s = "Hello World!" ;
```

is stored in read only memory and the string literal cannot be modified via the pointer.

How is this different from

```
const char *s = "Hello World!";
```

Also is the type of 'string' char * or const char * ?

Comment: The first way is deprecated and dangerous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By giving the type as `const char *`, it makes it harder to accidentally overwrite the memory, since the compiler will give an error if you try:

```
const char *s = "Hello World!";
s[0] = 'X';  // compile error
```

If you don't use `const`, then the problem may not be caught until runtime, or it may just cause your program to be subtly wrong.

Comment: oh yes i see that trying to modify char *s , compiles successfully but const char *s , doesn't. So basically putting const acts a red flag to not change the string. Cool !

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that the latter is legal and the former is not. That's a change that was made in C++11. Formally, `"Hello World!"` has type `const char[13]`; it can be converted to `const char*`. In the olden days, its type could be `char[13]`, which could be converted to `char*`. C++ changed the type of the array by adding the `const`, but kept the conversion to `char*` so that existing C code that used `char*` would work in C++, but modifying the text that the pointer pointed to produced undefined behavior. C++11 removed the conversion to `char*`, so now you can only legally do

```
const char *s = "Hello world!";
```

Comment: `C++11 removed the conversion to char*`  -- not in gcc48.   Is this gcc bug?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky - the conversion is not allowed in C++11. The rule is that the compiler must issue a diagnostic for a violation of a constraint that does not say "no diagnostic required". So all that's needed is a diagnostic, which is sometimes a warning.

Comment: If adding `const` changes the type, wouldn't `const<char*>` or `const<char[]>` be more logical?